# Graphite - graph a related metric form a series list

Tags: graphite, grafana

I want to graph the mean response time for the 10 API calls which are called the most.

I have:

`api.<route>.count
api.<route>.mean`

I want to graph the mean value for the series with the highest counts.

I have the 10 highest count by using the `highestCount( api.*.count )` so how do i take that list and replace `.count` with `.mean`

The `useSeriesAbove` method is very close to what i want... but I don't want to provide it with a static count.

> useSeriesAbove(seriesList, value, search, replace) Compares the
>   maximum of each series against the given value. If the series maximum
>   is greater than value, the regular expression search and replace is
>   applied against the series name to plot a related metric
>
> e.g. given useSeriesAbove(ganglia.metric1.reqs,10,’reqs’,’time’), the
>   response time metric will be plotted only when the maximum value of
>   the corresponding request/s metric is > 10
>
> &target=useSeriesAbove(ganglia.metric1.reqs,10,"reqs","time")

Answer (score 0):

Use `limit(sortByMaxima(api.<route>.mean),10)` for getting top 10 results.
Also, maybe mean time is not that you want if you want to measure latency - use 95th or 999th percentile - see https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10485804

Comment: Thanks but i'm looking to get the ```count``` for the 10 slowest ```mean```'s .  I"m using mean_90 generally just wanted to keep it simple.  Thanks for the link though i'll check it out.